# Vim custom syntax highlighting: highlight "word=value" without spaces in between

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I've asked this question on StackOverflow and they suggested to ask it here.
I am trying to set a custom syntax highlighting for BSD rc.conf file which looks like:

```
name=YES
anothername=NO
third="options"
```

I created years agoo a syntax file:

```
if version < 600
  syntax clear
elseif exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

if !exists("main_syntax")
  let main_syntax = 'sh'
endif

if version < 600
  so <sfile>:p:h/sh.vim
else
  runtime! syntax/sh.vim
  unlet b:current_syntax
endif

syntax case match

syn keyword rcconfKeywordYes YES
syn keyword rcconfKeywordNo NO

let b:current_syntax = "rcconf"

hi def link rcconfKeywordYes Type
hi def link rcconfKeywordNo Special
```

This worked before, but now in vim 8 it works only if there are spaces between keywords and other symbols:

```
name = YES
anothername = NO
```

Comment: So there is no highlighting at all of `foo=bar`? You say "years ago"...note that pre-vim 6 this was apparently not using the standard sh.vim syntax file so maybe that's the difference.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Have you tried using `dosini` filetype?

Answer (score 1):

It could depend on `iskeyword` value.
`keyword` only matches for a complete word, for example, if you define the keyword `NO`, it will not match `NOT` or `PIANO`.
If Vim considers `=` is a letter, then `anothername=NO` is a single word, and it's not `NO`.

You can check if Vim considers `=` to be a letter with `:set iskeyword?`.
You can probably fix it: with the command `:set iskeyword-==`, `YES` and `NO` will get colors.
With `:set iskeyword+==`, they lose they colors again.

You can also use the `syntax iskeyword` instead (it's not the same, for example it doesn't change abbrev behavior, and it is recommended to use this one).
It's explain at `:help syntax|3546`.
Try with: `:syntax iskeyword @,48-57,192-255,$,_`.

I don't know which one breaks your syntax, so you can try both.

Comment: Looks like you might be new here, but great couple of first answers! Welcome!

Comment: Thanks ! I already used stackexchange websites as "read only user" for at least several months, but only started giving answers since yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfotunatly it does not help. At the beginning `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`, after `set iskeyword-==` the same and no color, after `set iskeyword+==` the equal sign has been added  `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,=` and no colors appeared also

Comment: what is the output of the command `:syntax iskeyword` ?

Comment: `syntax iskeyword @,48-57,_,192-255,-`